# Update the inverse of sum of two symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, na.numerical-analysis, matrix-inverse

There are two invertible symmetric matrices *A* and *B*, of which *B* is a block diagonal. *A* and *B* have the same dimensions. I need to iteratively calculate the inverse of *M* = *s* * *A* + *B*, where *s* is a positive scalar and will be changed during iterations.

Is there a simple approach to update the inverse of *M* with respect to different values of *s*?

Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: As far as I know, **no**, unless you can afford to compute a generalized Schur decomposition (i.e., essentially compute all eigenvalues). In that case, you can solve systems with $O(n^2)$ each afterwards.

Comment: I suppose in some restricted circumstances you'd have a power series expansion for the inverse of $M$. It might not be useful, depending on your precise needs.